# RODBC - multiple tables in one sqlQuery() call

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I'm using RODBC to pull data into R from an existing SQL database. I am trying to call multiple queries/tables at once.

For example:

`test2=sqlQuery(channel,'select top 10 * from bug; select top 10 * from site')`

This only returns the first table. I am interested in doing this because I want to call a more complex stored procedure that other collaborators are using and continuing development on...this procedure returns 3 tables (which are set as temporary tables in the stored procedure (#) to meet our other data needs/uses).

So, when I call the stored procedure, similar to the two query scenario above, it only returns the first table as the result.

Any suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to get that to work in RODBC; as far as I know, it expects a single resultset from the database.

However, you could modify your SQL to get both values in a single query:

```
SELECT  
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM   bug) AS bugcount,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM   site) AS sitecount;
```